# Change a specific dialog font

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have the following android code that check for Google play service, if there is not, it will display an error dialog that can direct you directly to the Google play service download, so my question :
Is it possible and how can I change the dialog, for example change the font scale of the header and the body, ext...

thank you in advance.

the code:

```
public Boolean isGooglePlay( ) {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);


    if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        return true;
    }
    else{

        //I want to change the following dialog:

        ((Dialog) GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 10)).show();



        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what 'police' is here

Comment: I think it is by default

Comment: I don't think "police" means what you think it means.

Comment: I want to make the title for example BOLD and the content italic for example...

Answer (score 1):

There are no documented and supported means of styling this dialog.

Since this dialog is not open source, there is no way to readily discover undocumented and unsupported means of styling the dialog. And, even if you reverse-engineered the code, you would need to do that every time you take on an update to the Play Services SDK, as they may have changed their implementation.

I recommend that you leave Google's dialog alone, from a styling standpoint.